# LNK2019: Unresolved External Symbol when attempting to use "GetCommPorts()"

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am attempting to retrieve a list of COM ports in a windows program using the [`GetCommPorts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcommports) function.

```
#include<WinBase.h>

void CSoftwareDlg::DynamicComPortMenu()
{
    ULONG portNumbers[100];
    ULONG portsFound;
    ULONG CommPorts = GetCommPorts(portNumbers, 100, &portsFound);

    if (CommPorts == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        OutputDebugString("COM Ports retrieved successfully.");
        OutputDebugString(("Found" + std::to_string(portsFound) + "ports.").c_str());
        for (auto i = 0; i < portsFound; i++) {
            OutputDebugString(("\t" + std::to_string(portNumbers[i])).c_str());
        }
    }
    else if (CommPorts == ERROR_MORE_DATA) {
        OutputDebugString("Array to small to retrieve all port numbers.");
    }
    else if (CommPorts == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
        OutputDebugString("No COM ports found.");
    }
    else {
        OutputDebugString("CommPorts function not equal to any of the standard error codes...");
    }

}
```

The function call has no compiler error, and I can peek the definition of the function without issue. For other similar issues, I've resolved this issue with the scope resolution operator or the macro definition  and scope resolution operator like so:

```
::GetCommPorts(portNumbers, 100, &portsFound);
```

```
_WINBASE_::GetCommPorts(portNumbers, 100, &portsFound);
```

I thought that it may be in some "hidden" library, so I took a shot in the dark and attempted to use a pragma comment to find a WinBase library like so:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "Winbase.lib")
```

What am I missing here? The fact that I'm able to peek the definition of the function is really throwing me off.

Bonus question: Should I always be handling all of the return codes for functions like this(e.g. `ERROR_SUCCESS`, `ERROR_MORE_DATA`, and `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`)?

Comment: Read the page you linked all the way to the bottom. The "*hidden library*" is `OneCore.lib`.

Comment: So close... yet so far. Thanks again @dvix.